# How to repeat same network request multiple times(different parameters) in RxJava/RxAndroid?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

So, I have a `/download` API which returns me a generic `Object` (based on an index number which is its own parameter) then I have to save it to my database, if the transaction is successful, I have to increase my index and repeat the same process again, otherwise `retry()`.

I'll need to repeat this for about 50 times.

How can I achieve this process using Rx-Java? 
I'm stuck right now. Any help would be awesome. Thank You.

Comment: I think it's more likely to face an HTTP error rather than a transaction error. So, the http layer has a bigger need for retry mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Observable.range(1, 50)
    .flatMap(index ->      // for every index make new request
        makeRequest(index) // this shall return Observable<Response>
            .retry(N)      // on error => retry this request N times
    )
    .subscribe(response -> saveToDb(response));
```

Answer to comment (make new request only after previous response is saved to db):

```
Observable.range(1, 50)
    .flatMap(index ->      // for every index make new request
        makeRequest(index) // this shall return Observable<Response>
            .retry(N)      // on error => retry this request N times
            .map(response -> saveToDb(response)), // save and report success
        1                  // limit concurrency to single request-save
    )
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: i tried your answer and it seems to call another API instantly.

Is there any way to wait for the result, save it to db and then and only then, call a new API ??

Comment: @gubaju In order to achieve that you can move save operation into request pipeline and limit `flatMap` concurrency to 1.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly this piece of code should point you to a right direction.

```
        BehaviorSubject<Integer> indexes = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0);
        indexes.flatMap(integer -> Observable.just(integer)) // download operation
               .flatMap(downloadedObject -> Observable.just(integer)) // save operation
               .doOnNext(ind -> indexes.onNext(ind + 1))
               .subscribe(ind -> System.out.println("Index " + ind));
```

What happens is:

1. BehaviorSubject is a sort of initiator of whole work, it feeds indexes
   to the chain.
2. First flatMap is where you do a download operation
3. Second flatMap is where you save it to a DB
4. In doOnNext you have to
   issue onNext or onComplete to the subject to continue with or finish
   processing. (This can be done in a subscriber)

Remember to add a stop condition in the `onNext` to not end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: so how do i pass my value received from first flatMap(API) to my second flatmap(db).

Comment: It is passed automatically, in here I named those variables integer but in fact of the first flatMap returns object i.e. User it becomes input of the second flatMap.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll need to repeat this for about 50 times.

You can use `range` operator and handle each Int emitted.

> if the transaction is successful, I have to increase my index

In that case you need to use `concatMap` operator. It handles each `Observable` sequentially.

```
Observable<Response> makeRequest(int i) {...}

Completable saveToDb(Response response) {...}

Observable.range(1, 50)
    .concatMap(i -> makeRequest(i)
                        //I assume that you save your response to DB asynchronously
                        //if not - use doOnNext operator instead of flatMapCompletable
                        .flatMapCompletable(response -> saveToDb(response)
                        .toObservable())
    .retry()
    ...
```

Comment: I had similar problems with this code as answered by @Yaroslav. **makeRequest()** gets called instantly. It should get called only after successful database save.

Comment: `concatMap` waits for `onComplete` for each `Observable`. In my example it's combined `Observable` that contains `makeRequest` and `saveToDb`. Seems something wrong with your implementation. However i edited my answer to fix code formatting. Please post your code.